# PL/SQL using outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, outer-join

I have 3 tables:

- A (t_ref integer, l_date date),
- B (t_ref integer, client_ref integer),
- C (t_id integer, client_ref integer)
  and parameter (client_ref_ integer).

I need to select data from table A with condition:
1) if there are rows in table B connected with client_ref (if query

```
select b.t_ref from B b where b.client_ref = client_ref_
```

returns any data),  my query will look like this:

```
select max(l_date) from A where t_ref in (select b.t_ref from B b where b.client_ref = client_ref_)
```

2) if the query above returns any data, my query will look like this:

```
 select max(l_date) from A where t_ref in (select c.t_id from C c where c.client_ref = client_ref_)
```

Now I've written a PLSQL function:

```
  select max(aa.l_date) into l_date from A aa where aa.t_ref in (select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = client_ref_);
  if l_date is null then
    select max(aa.l_date) into l_date from A aa where t_ref in (select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = client_ref_);
  end if;
return l_date;
```

It works, but it isn't good idea, because I call table A 2 times. Is it possible to avoid second call, and do this in one query?

Comment: In you function the first select will fail. You had aliased your table as aa and using single a in your select query. max(a.l_date) into l_date

Comment: Sorry, it was typinq mistake. But it isn't a main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
     prep ( t_ref, idx ) as (
       select  b.t_ref, 1
         from  table_B b 
         where b.client_ref = :client_ref 
       union all
       select  c.t_ref, 2
         from  table_C c 
         where c.client_ref = :client_ref 
     )
select max(a.l_date) keep (dense_rank first order by p.idx) -- into l_date
from   table_A a inner join prep p
                 on a.t_ref = p.t_ref
;
```

Explanation: First scan `table_B` for rows with matching `client_ref`; if any are found, collect them and attach an "index" of `1`. Then scan `table_C` and do the same, but with index `2`. (If `table_C` is very large, this is wasted time when `:client_ref` was found in `table_B`; if that is a concern, it can be addressed with a little more code). Then `table_A` is joined to the result of putting these two sets of rows together. `keep dense_rank first...` will make sure only rows with`idx = 1` are considered for `max(l_date)`, but if no such rows exist only the rows with `idx = 2` will be considered.

If `:client_ref` is not found in either of tables B and C, the resulting `max(l_date)` will be `null`.

I wrote the query with `:clent_ref` as a bind variable so I could test the query; you may change it to your variable name `client_ref_`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way : I covered all your case here. Please verify

```
create  table A (t_ref integer, l_date date);

create   table B (t_ref integer, client_ref integer);

create   table C (t_id integer, client_ref integer);



 SQL> select * from a
  2  /

     T_REF L_DATE
---------- ---------
        10 01-JAN-11
        20 02-FEB-11
        30 02-MAR-11

SQL> select * from b;

     T_REF CLIENT_REF
---------- ----------
        10        101
        20        102

SQL> select * from c;

      T_ID CLIENT_REF
---------- ----------
        10        101
        20        102
        30        101
        40        103




sql> select max(aa.l_date) 
    --into l_date 
    from A aa 
    where aa.t_ref =any(   case when ( select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = '101' and rownum <2 ) is null then
                                     ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '101' )
                                     when  ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '101' and rownum <2 ) is not null then
                                      ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '101' and rownum <2   )
                                      else
                                     ( select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = '101' )
                                     end
                         );

MAX(AA.L_
---------
01-JAN-11



SQL> select max(aa.l_date) 
--into l_date 
from A aa 
where aa.t_ref =any(   case when ( select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = '102' and rownum <2 ) is null then
                                 ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '102' )
                                 when  ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '102' and rownum <2 ) is not null then
                                      ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '102'   )
                                  else
                                 ( select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = '102' )
                                     end
                     );

MAX(AA.L_
---------
02-FEB-11


SQL> select max(aa.l_date) 
--into l_date 
from A aa 
where aa.t_ref =any(   case when ( select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = '103' and rownum <2 ) is null then
                                 ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '103' )
                                 when  ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '103' and rownum <2 ) is not null then
                                  ( select t_id from C c where c.client_ref = '103'  )
                                  else
                                 ( select bb.t_ref from B bb where bb.client_ref = '103' )
                                     end
                     );

MAX(AA.L_
---------


SQL>
```

Comment: It returns error: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Can you share some sample data of your table a,b,c

Comment: A: ((10, '01.01.2011'), (20, '02.02.2011'), (30, '02.03.2011'), (40, '04.04.2011'))  
B: ((10, 101), (20, 102))  
C: ((10, 101), (20, 102), (30, 101), (40, 103)).

Comment: If I do my function for client 101, it will return 01.01.2011, because there is a record in table B connected with client 101. If I call my function to client 102, it will return 02.02.2011. And if I call my function for client 103, it will return 04.04.2011, because there aren't records in table B connected with 104 client, but there is such record in table C.

Comment: If i run my query wit your data set its blank..not giving any error as such..You try running the query with the data you give and check if there is any error

Comment: If you check my query i have joined A and B with t_ref...I guess then 101 will not return anything..I guess you need to modify the join ,

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no rights to modify tables. CASE statement must return only one record? My error can be caused by this - in my data your subquery in CASE returns multiple rows.

Comment: Also you will not get any records in your last case when you pass 103 coz your table A has missing ref id. See my results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select max(aa.l_date) into l_date from A aa 
    where t_ref in 
    (SELECT t_ref from (select t_id t_ref,client_ref_ client_ref_ from C c
                          UNION
                        select t_ref t_ref,client_ref_ client_ref_ from B b) 
                       tmp where tmp.client_ref = client_ref_)
return l_date;
```

Comment: I don't need UNION. it will return all records from C and all records from B connected with `client_ref_` in any case, but I need records from B if they exist, and if they don't exist, I need records from C.

Comment: What do you mean by exist.. could you share sample data from all 3 tables.

Comment: If there are rows in table B connected with `client_ref_`, I need them. If there aren't rows in B connected with `client_ref_`, I need to select all rows from C connected with `client_ref_`